# Unable to add array of views to parent view on titanium android

Tags: view, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I do not want to use a table view. The above code works fine with iOS but crashes on Android.

```
var rowViewList = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    rowViewList.push(Alloy.createController("untilNextTime/minifigureTradingRow", {
        data : data[i]          
    }).getView());                      
}
$.parentFrameTrade.add(rowViewList); // This is the line where android crashes.parentFrameTrade is a normal view.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documented](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-method-add) the `add()` method only accepts a single view. You are right it works on iOS and we might make this official and have parity but not atm.